# How to refresh a page once automatically right after it loads completely without changing or adding a string in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a script that looks for a particular class and once found appends a div to it. In order for this to work the page needs to be refreshed once without changing the url in the address bar, its like simulating the act of actually hitting the refresh button on the browser. Almost all answers I see here in Stack Overflow requires a string to be attached in the end of the url for the one time refresh to work. Is there actually a way to automatically refresh once after the page loads without changing the url in the address bar?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `location.reload();`

Furthermore, you can use the `localStorage` property to store whether you have reloaded the page once so you don't reload forever.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: the problem with this is it reloads endlessly. I just need to reload the page once right after it completely loads.

Comment: How many times do you need it to reload? The first time they ever come to the page? First time that day? Anyways you could use local storage to store whatever you need.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: just once per visit to that page.

Comment: Yeah localstorage should be fine, just store that they have visited in some variable. Then when you start the page look at that variable and reload if they're there for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this with true `location.reload(true)`